# How to get response body in axios when the status is 400?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm developing an application and I want to use the status code 400 when a user sends
invalid or incomplete data, but when axios receives a 400 status code it throws an error
and I can't get the response from it, it just gives me a error that includes the request but not the response, how am I supposed to handle this?

```js
const getIdTypes = () => {
  return axios_instance.get
    (idTypesUrl)
}


const getValidIdTypes = async () => {
  return infoActions.getIdTypes()
  .then(res => {
    if (res.status !== 200 && res.status !== 201) {
      pushToFlasher(res.data)
    }
    setValidIdTypes(res.data)
  })
  .catch(err => {
    if (err.request) {
      console.log("err:", err.request)
    }
     if (err.response) {
      console.log("err:", err.response)
    }
    // pushToFlasher(err.response.data)
  })
}
```

Comment: can you show how you have the api call setup?

Answer (score 10):

You can specify which status codes are valid when you create an instance:

```
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'some api url',
  timeout: 1000 * 30,
  validateStatus: (status) => {
    return status >= 200 && status < 500
  },
})
```

So here all statuses between 200 and 500, will be considered valid and not throw an error.

In your case you can just `return status === 400`

Comment: thank you so much, I was about to stab my knees with a brick.

Comment: still can't get the body, don't know why

Comment: thanks, I fixed it, it was part axios and part my api, thank you so much again

Answer (score 1):

in catch block, you can access error response that server sends by getting `err.response.data` object:

```
const getValidIdTypes = async () => {
  return infoActions.getIdTypes()
  .then(res => {
    if (res.status !== 200 && res.status !== 201) {
      pushToFlasher(res.data)
    }
    setValidIdTypes(res.data)
  })
  .catch(err => {
      console.log(err.response.data)
  })
}
```

for exmaple if server send this object:

```
{
    status: 400,
    message: "there is a problem"
}
```

you can get "message" this way:
`err.response.data.message`

Comment: This is much better solution - totally non intrusive and lets you handle the error the way you want.